# Memory Error Python on neo4j

Tags: python, database, graph, neo4j

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
import psycopg2
db = GraphDatabase("http://127.0.0.1:7474",username="neo4j", password="neo4j")
conn = psycopg2.connect("\
   dbname='bdTrmmTest'\
   user='postgres'\
   host='127.0.0.1'\
   password='1234'\
   ");
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT latitude, longitude, gid FROM pontos")  
records = c.fetchall() #pega todos os resultados do select e armazena em uma tupla
e = conn.cursor()
e.execute("SELECT precipitacaoh, gidgeo_fk FROM historico")
records2 = e.fetchall()
#cria todos os sensores os latitude e longitute
sensorlatlong = db.labels.create("Latitude/Longitude")
sensorprecip = db.labels.create("Precipitacao")
for j in records2:
    s2 = db.nodes.create(precipitacao=j[0])
    sensorprecip.add(s2)
    for i in records:
        if(i[2]==j[1]):
            s = db.nodes.create(latitude=i[0],longitutde=i[1])
            sensorlatlong.add(s)
            s.relationships.create("MARCOU",s2)
```

I want import a relational databse to graph database, the following error appears: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bdTrmmTest.py", line 15, in 
    records2 = e.fetchall()
MemoryError